# How to save custom form data into database in magento 2.4

Tags: php, magento2

I have a custom for (ss below). [image]

The problem I am having is that, When I add something and then click on save button, it redirects me to Catalog/Category when the form is located in CONTENT/Element/Frequently Asked Questions and has nothing to do with Catalog/Category.

I don't know why it would go to Catalog/category and when it redirects to Category page, it also gives me an error (ss below)[image]

Below is my Save.php located under Magebit\Faq\Controller\Adminhtml\Question\Save.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Magebit\Faq\Controller\Adminhtml\Question;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
    ) {
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Save action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if ($data) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

            $model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magebit\Faq\Model\Question::class)->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId() && $id) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This Add new FAQ form no longer exists.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }
            $model->setData($data);

            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the Faq.'));
                $this->dataPersistor->clear('faqquestionform');

                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId()]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the faq form.'));
            }

            $this->dataPersistor->set('faqquestionform', $data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

The other Save.php located under Magebit\faq\Ui\Component\Form\Button\Save.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 *
 * Created By: MageDelight Pvt. Ltd.
 */
namespace Magebit\Faq\Ui\Component\Form\Button;
use Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Edit\GenericButton;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Control\Container;
class Save extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Get button data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Save'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'faq_question_form.faq_question_form',
                                'actionName' => 'save',
                                'params' => [false],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'class_name' => Container::SPLIT_BUTTON,
            'options' => $this->getOptions(),
        ];
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        $options[] = [
            'id_hard' => 'save_and_close',
            'label' => __('Save & Close'),
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'faq_question_form.faq_question_form',
                                'actionName' => 'save',
                                'params' => [true],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

and below is my custom form called faq_question_form.xml located under Magebit\Faq\view\adminhtml\ui_component where I have this save button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">faq_question_form.faq_question_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Information</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="reverseMetadataMerge" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="back" class="Magebit\Faq\Ui\Component\Form\Button\Back"/>
            <button name="save" class="Magebit\Faq\Ui\Component\Form\Button\Save"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>faq_question_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>faq_question_form.faq_question_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="faq_question_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validateUrl path="catalog/category/validate"/>
            <submitUrl path="catalog/category/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Magebit\Faq\Model\Question\DataProvider" name="faq_question_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general" sortOrder="5">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>false</collapsible>
            <label/>
        </settings>
        <field name="id" formElement="hidden">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="parent" formElement="hidden">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="path" formElement="hidden">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="level" formElement="hidden">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="store_id" formElement="hidden">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>number</dataType>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="is_active" sortOrder="10" formElement="checkbox">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Enable Question</label>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <checkbox>
                    <settings>
                        <valueMap>
                            <map name="false" xsi:type="string">0</map>
                            <map name="true" xsi:type="string">1</map>
                        </valueMap>
                        <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                    </settings>
                </checkbox>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        <field name="question" sortOrder="30" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Question</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="answer" formElement="textarea" sortOrder="40">
            <settings>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Answer</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My custom module folder structure is is below ss:

[image]

How can I get the data from this custom form and save into my custom db table without it redirecting to a random place?